# Reduce size of 'bottom corner' for seconday click

Tags: macos, multi-touch

Is there a way to reduce the size of the 'bottom' corner of the touchpad that responds as the secondary click?  It's way to big and I would like to make it the bottom corner, not bottom quadrant.

Comment: Bottom corner of what, precisely?

Comment: sorry, didn't think omitting Touch-pad would cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As such there is no way to reduce the size of the 'bottom' corner. What you can do is enable "Click or tap with two fingers" if clicking at bottom corner doesn't work out well for you. This option is available in Trackpad menu of system preferences.

Comment: thanks, but the tapping action is way to sensitive and I get spurious things happening on my Mac that frighten the hell out of me.